# How can I set a character limit of 100 without splitting words?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, split

I want to cut a string every 100 characters without cutting up words.

```
var TmpArray=[];
var str = 'this string will be cut up after every 100 characters but it will cut into words';
str=str.replace(/[^a-z A-Z0-9]+/g, '');
str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
var sp=(str.match(new RegExp(" ", "g")) || []).length;
var max=100;
//Spaces will be converted into %20 (later) so each space must count as 3 characters.
var FoundSpaces=sp*3;
var tmp=max-FoundSpaces;
var cut=str.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+tmp+'}', 'g'));
for (i = 0; i < cut.length; i++){
    TmpArray.push(cut[i]);
}
console.log(TmpArray);
```

Output: `["this string will be cut up after every 100 characters b", "ut it will cut into words"]`

So how can I prevent it from splitting words like it did?

Comment: Good. What have you tried?

Comment: did you write any code for this?

Comment: Sorry it's on the sloppy side, reason for the bit of math is because all spaces will be converted into %20 later on. So for every space i -3.

Comment: 1+ Why is this downvoted? Seems like a perfectly interesting question.

Comment: I don't know, maybe someone thought my code was a failed attempt to answer my own question.

Comment: @NewToJS what should be the expected output? Should the word ‘but’ in the first group or second?

Comment: @WebDegBrian The output in my question is the output I were getting from my attempt. The expected out put is very clear *"cut a string every 100 characters without cutting up words"* and a solution for this post has been provided.

Comment: @NewToJS It is kind of hard for me to understand it. So the word ‘but’ should be in the second group of your output right? (The output you gave in the question). And I just want to test myself if I can solve it

Comment: @WebDegBrian If the split of the string will be 100 or less characters then yes but if putting that word into the array exceeds the character limit then it should be used in the next array instead. Please look at the accepted answer. This gives a great example of what  I were looking for when I posted this in **2014**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. I will propose one more implementation of how you can use just array methods, combination of `split` + `reduce`:

```js
var str = 'This example of the string that we want to split by spaces only making sure that individual chunk is less or equal to specified number.';

// Split by spaces
str.split(/\s+/)

// Then join words so that each string section is less then 40
.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (prev.length && (prev[prev.length - 1] + ' ' + curr).length <= 40) {
        prev[prev.length - 1] += ' ' + curr;
    }
    else {
        prev.push(curr);
    }
    return prev;
}, [])

// Print for testting
.forEach(function(str) {
    console.log(str + ' ' + str.length);
});
```

For this example I set maximum length of 40 characters.

Output:

```
This example of the string that we want 39
to split by spaces only making sure that 40
individual chunk is less or equal to 36
specified number. 17
```

#### One more demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9tgo6n1t/

Comment: Sorry but i just can't get this working. As you can see from my username i'm new with javascript hence my basic attempt to split the string. Maybe you could post something i can test that works or you could explain how i get the above to work so i can console.log() results and learn from this. I'm not expecting a quick copy/paste, i would like to learn from my own question. Thanks.

Comment: I posted the example in my answer, it works well. Did you check you console when you press "run code snippet"?

Comment: When i get this working the console log outputs word for word with the length, it doesn't keep everything inline as your Output example shows.
This 4
example 7 
Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the string be in a variable? the string i will be using will be given from another function so having a string sit like that and not know how to change it isn't any use for me. Normally i would put the string in a variable...

Comment: Of course you can use variable, I just bypassed variable creation. See updated answer.

Comment: Well that helps. I'm new with Javascript as i said before so explaining your code is always helpful otherwise a copy/paste isn't helping anyone learn from the question. Thank you for helping me understand and answering my question.