# Javascript: insert &nbsp; every nth character without splitting words and adding the nbsp into the count

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Without going too much into detail, some basic facts: I'm not a web developer, I don't really know javascript, just enough to make me dangerous. We utilize a website integration third-party software, that takes data from our ERP inventory system, and creates web pages, for products, ordering, etc... and then syncs it back into our ERP, using an SQL database. Part of this packages includes an HTML editor that was added to our inventory system to help create listings. This HTML code is then broken up into SQL varchar(250). When the website is ultimately generated we end up with merged words every 250 characters. To keep the examples shorter, and because the solution shouldn't matter, let's assume it's varchar(100) and merges words every 100 characters:

> Example: This is an example and it runs 140 characters long, and this
>   is how you would expect it to look on a website when presented to the
>   end user.
>
> Our Website: This is an example and it runs 140 characters long, and
>   this is how you would expect it to look on awebsite when presented to
>   the end user.

I've merged the words "a" and "website" to be "awebsite" as that is what happens. It never breaks words, and always just removes the space before the word that would cause it to break 100 characters.

Now, some are probably going to ask, "Why not have the third-party company fix this?" We tried, it was a costly integration, and they could not figure out why or how to fix it after 2 months, and eventually said it was costing too much to fix the bug that they were not going to solve it, and if we wanted to we could pay more to have them come up with a solution.

We came up with our own solution, simply find the 100th character, and right before whatever word that was insert a   so my HTML code looked like this:

```
<p>This is an example and it runs 140 characters long, and this is how you would expect it to look on a &nbsp;website when presented to the end user.</p>
```

Okay, this works, but its very labor intensive when you have 500+ character count descriptions, and the SQL table takes into consideration all code as characters, every time we manually add a &nbps; it adds 6 characters, making us need to recount the next string etc...

So I'm trying to create a simple form, easy enough:

```js
$(function ()
              {
                  $("#btnSubmitTwo").on("click", function ()
                  {
                      var html = "<p>{{inputHTML}}</p>";
                      $(".input").each(function (i, v)
                      {
                          v = $(v);
                          html = html.replace(new RegExp("{{" + v.attr("id") + "}}", 'g'), v.val());
                          html = html.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
                      });
      
                      $("#htmlResultHTML").val(html);
                  })
              });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-1">Description:</div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-11"><textarea cols="82" rows="5" type="text" id="inputHTML" class="input"></textarea>
      <small id="fitmentinline" class="text-muted">Enter Description.</small>
      </div>
              </div>
      
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmitTwo">Submit</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
      
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <textarea readonly id="htmlResultHTML" cols="100" rows="100"></textarea>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

This was my attempt at a solution, just to replace all spaces with hard coded spaces. But of course this inserts a new problem. Strings now break divs/tables etc... and just run on in a single line until they end, web browsers cannot word wrap this solution. So, I tried to find more advanced solutions, but I am not skillful enough to merge these solutions into one that solves my specific problem.

> **Goal:** To have that simple form, that spits out a HTML code, but instead of inserting a nbsp; in EVERY space, only have it insert a nbsp; right after the space after the last full word before reaching 100 characters. However it cannot replace the space that is there, just add a new hard-coded one. Then repeat itself and count the next 100 characters, including the +6 characters added by inserting the nbps;

So we would end up with something that looked identical to our manual code:

```
<p>This is an example and it runs 140 characters long, and this is how you would expect it to look on a &nbsp;website when presented to the end user.</p>
```

And taken further:

```
<p>This is an example and it runs 140 characters long, and this is how you would expect it to look on a &nbsp;website when presented to the end user. This is an example and it runs 140 characters long, &nbsp;and this is how you would expect it to look on a website when presented to the end user.</p>
```

Here is the research I've done so far, but have unsuccessfully tried to implement:

[How can I set a character limit of 100 without splitting words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507116/how-can-i-set-a-character-limit-of-100-without-splitting-words)

[How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to change the db column type?

Comment: I would find a new third party provider. That's actually one of the most ridiculous things I've ever heard.

Comment: Where is the code that takes the `varchar(250)` chunks and joins them together? Can you change that?

Comment: @HansZ I wish, I've dove into that but there's literally 5000+ files in the website, and I couldn't find it among all the .vb and .aspx and other files referenced for this particular line, and eventually it all boils down into combined libraries and code that affects more than just this part, like links to instruction documents/etc... that I wouldn't want a space added and any fields are supposed to be merged, so I was afraid if I messed too much with it, I'd break more stuff than I'd fix. Also, they gave up, so I'm assuming it's too hard to fix via their code.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure, this particular code is used for more than just this single field, so I'm not sure how it would affect other pieces of their enormous website/code. Since this db column is used for 30-40 different elements, not just this one thing that doesn't display correctly.

Comment: What happens when the 100th character is in the middle of a word?

Comment: @HansZ I thought I explained that above, but maybe not clearly enough. The way it is working currently, is that when it creates the SQL tables from the html it creates them in full words, so if the next word would be char's 98,99,100,102,103, that entire word would be moved to the next SQL row, along with the next 100 characters of words. So what we're doing manually is counting to 100, then adding the nbsp to the front of that word we're in the middle of, then we start back at the nbsp, and count 100 again, add nbsp, etc.. etc..

Comment: This is honestly such a needlessly hard problem to fix on your end. To do this automatically you need to write a function that reads a dictionary of english words to decide where to insert the space in a concatenated word, e.g. where does the space go in "woodsteak"? "wood steak" or "woods teak". It should be fairly simple to fix for your provider, they just need to join the sql results together with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Should be pretty good.

```
var testString = "This is a long sentence for testing the code made. This is a long sentence for testing the code made.This is a long sentence for testing the code made.";
var output = "";
var arr = testString.split(" ");

var maxLength = 50;
var section = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  var v = section + arr[i];
  if (v.length >= maxLength) {
    if(output.length != 0) output += "&nbsp;";
    output += section;
    section = arr[i] + " ";
  }
  else if(arr.length == i){
    output += section;
  }
  else{
    section = v + " ";
  }
}
console.info(output);
```

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I needed!

Comment: Minor adjustment, it was dropping the "&nbsp;" on the last maxLength string, so I changed the else if to read:
`else if(arr.length == i){
    output += "&nbsp;";
    output += section;
    }`