# How to break an array in multiple rows in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

i am stuck on a little (and maybe not so hard) problem in a function for pdf-creation.
It´s my first time with typescript so maybe the answer is simple and i just cant see it :P ( and i am a beginner in programming (1year))

I need to make sure, that if a company has a veeery long name (up to 180 letters), that the pdf looks still good and the long name will be split down in multiple rows.

i have the companyName for 180 letters. "Firmenname der vollkommen fiktiv ist um eine PDF für den maximalst unwahrscheinlichsten Firmennamen anzupassen damit es noch gut oder zumindest passabel aussieht da es sich um ein."

i managed to split it in 3 rows but have trouble with the second row, because this row doesnt stop at 60letters.
[enter image description here][1]

my code for the splitting is following. So, basically the rsult for "company2" is the problem.

```
else if (companyLength > 120 && companyLength <= 180) {
    let words = companyName.split(' ');
    let newLength = 0;
    let company1 = '';
    let company2 = '';
    let company3 = '';
    let i = 0;
    let o = 0;
    let j = 0;
    let k = 0;        
    while (newLength + words[i].length <= 60) {
        newLength += words[i].length + 1;
        i++;
        o++;
        o++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        company1 += words[j] + ' ';
    }
    
    for (k = j; k < words.length; k++) {
        company2 += words[k] + ' ';
    }
    for (let f = o; f < words.length; f++) {
        company3 += words[f] + ' ';
    }
    doc.text(company1, 22, 46);
    doc.text(company2, 22, 50);
    doc.text(company3, 22, 54);
```

Has somebody a tip how i can achive the wished result, so the second line doesnt break trough the borders and break properly?

kind regards and thx in advance for your help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2akxs.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?
Explanation is in the comments

```js
const name = "Firmenname der vollkommen fiktiv ist um eine PDF für den maximalst unwahrscheinlichsten Firmennamen anzupassen damit es noch gut oder zumindest passabel aussieht da es sich um ein."

function process(name) {
  // if length is less than 180, only one row
  if (name.length < 180) return [name]
  
  // otherise three strings for each row
  // each is array of characters which joined later
  const parts = [[], [], []]
  let partsIdx = 0

  for (const char of name) {
    parts[partsIdx].push(char)
  
    // if the current row has already 60 characters
    // and is not the last row
    if (partsIdx != (parts.length - 1) && parts[partsIdx].length >= 60) {
      partsIdx++
    }
  }
  
  // join the array of characters to form strings
  return parts.map(p => p.join(''))
}

console.log(process(name))
```

Comment: Yeah that helps alot, thank you very much. The only little problem left is, that it should split the companyName between the spaces, so that no words got cutoff in the middle when they reach the end of the line.   i tink i can figure it out with the help of you code :)   thx again

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion if you don't particularly need to split it into three lines, and just want the longest first line possible within your limit (maybe you picked 3 randomly as the most you will ever need to split it by?).

Since you aren't using typescript explicitly in your code, and types can be inferred from something this simple, the answer would be the same in javascript - it's similar to this question: [How can I set a character limit of 100 without splitting words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507116/how-can-i-set-a-character-limit-of-100-without-splitting-words)

```
const name = "Firmenname der vollkommen fiktiv ist um eine PDF für den maximalst unwahrscheinlichsten Firmennamen anzupassen damit es noch gut oder zumindest passabel aussieht da es sich um ein."

// guessing this is the max line length you want?
const maxLineLength = 120

// Split it by spaces with regex
const words = name.split(/\s+/)

const chunks = words.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (prev.length && (prev[prev.length - 1] + ' ' + curr).length <= maxLineLength) {
        prev[prev.length - 1] += ' ' + curr;
    }
    else {
        prev.push(curr);
    }
    return prev;
}, []);

//print the split lines to check
chunks.forEach((str) => {
    console.log(str);
});

//"Firmenname der vollkommen fiktiv ist um eine PDF für den maximalst unwahrscheinlichsten Firmennamen anzupassen damit es"
//"noch gut oder zumindest passabel aussieht da es sich um ein."
```

Comment: Thank you. Found another way to solve my problem but very good to know about this possibility :)